# Pass date command as parameter to kubernetes cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, cron, luigi

I want to execute data migration through Kubernetes cronjob using Luigi pipeline. My luigi task receives `--start` parameter which I want to pass through cronjob command.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: migration
spec:
  schedule: "0 0 */1 * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: spark
          containers:
          - name: migratecronjob
            image: latest-image
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            env:
              - name: TAG
                value: latest-image
              - name: MIGRATION_TAG
                value: migration-v05
            command:
              -  "luigi"
              - "--module" 
              - "module.task" 
              - "Migrate10Days"
              - "--start"
              - $(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H)
              - "--workers"
              - "10"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

The cronjob cannot recognize the `$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H)` as a bash script and pass this command as string to the luigi task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what are you going to archive, but this should work:

```
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - 'exec luigi --module module.task Migrate10Days --start $(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H) --workers --workers'
```

Comment: The missing explanation for the above snippet is that the whole command needs to be wrapped with an explicit shell `sh -c ...` which can interpret the `$(date ..)` subshell. Otherwise k8s will pass it in verbatim to the specified command `luigi`.

Comment: The title is misleading. It should read "Pass date command as parameter to kubernetes pod's container command". It has nothing to do with the cronjob per se, which is what I came here looking for.