# passing system date as variable to Kubernetes CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, cron, etcd

I found this [Pass date command as parameter to kubernetes cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364453/pass-date-command-as-parameter-to-kubernetes-cronjob)  which is similar, but did not solve my problem.

I'm trying to backup etcd using a cronjob, but etcd image doesn't have "date" command.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: backup
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - -c
            - etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
              --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
              snapshot save /backup/etcd-snapshot-$(DATE_CURR).db
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            env:
            - name: ETCDCTL_API
              value: "3"
            - name: DATE_CURR
              #value: $(date --date= +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z")
              value: $(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z")
            image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: backup
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
              name: etcd-certs
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /backup
              name: backup
          - args:
            - -c
            - find /backup -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            env:
            - name: ETCDCTL_API
              value: "3"
            image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: cleanup
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /backup
              name: backup
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          hostNetwork: true
          nodeName: homelab-a
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          volumes:
          - hostPath:
              path: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
              type: DirectoryOrCreate
            name: etcd-certs
          - hostPath:
              path: /opt/etcd_backups
              type: DirectoryOrCreate
            name: backup
  schedule: 0 */6 * * *
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
```

when this runs, it produces a file named "etcd-snapshot-.db", no date.  If I can catch the logs, it says that "date" is not a known command.  Sure enough, when I am able to exec into the pod while it's running, date does not work in the etcd image.   How can I pass the date from the system as a variable so that it just uses the text and not try to actually invoke the "date" command?

Edit:  Thanks to @Andrew, here is the solution:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: backup
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - -c
            - etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
              --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
              snapshot save /backup/etcd-snapshot-$(echo `printf "%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z)T\n"`).db
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            env:
            - name: ETCDCTL_API
              value: "3"
            image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: backup
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
              name: etcd-certs
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /backup
              name: backup
          - args:
            - -c
            - find /backup -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            env:
            - name: ETCDCTL_API
              value: "3"
            image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: cleanup
            resources: {}
            terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
            terminationMessagePolicy: File
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /backup
              name: backup
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          hostNetwork: true
          nodeName: homelab-a
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          securityContext: {}
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          volumes:
          - hostPath:
              path: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
              type: DirectoryOrCreate
            name: etcd-certs
          - hostPath:
              path: /opt/etcd_backups
              type: DirectoryOrCreate
            name: backup
  schedule: 0 */6 * * *
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  suspend: false
```

Comment: You can run an `initContainer:` using `busybox` to write the timestamp to either an `emptyDir: {}` or to `/backups/.current`, although TBH you're likely better off using [an existing tool](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/operations/etcd_backup_restore_encryption/#backup-and-restore-using-etcd-manager)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use printf like this:

```
printf "%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z)T\n"
```

Use `man strftime` to get conversion specification sequences.

Just tried it inside etcd container in kubernetes 1.19,

```
etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key snapshot save /tmp/etcd-snapshot-$(printf "%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z)T\n").db 
{"level":"info","ts":1603748998.7475638,"caller":"snapshot/v3_snapshot.go:119","msg":"created temporary db file","path":"/tmp/etcd-snapshot-2020-10-26_21:49:58_UTC.db.part"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2020-10-26T21:49:58.760Z","caller":"clientv3/maintenance.go:200","msg":"opened snapshot stream; downloading"}
{"level":"info","ts":1603748998.7616487,"caller":"snapshot/v3_snapshot.go:127","msg":"fetching snapshot","endpoint":"https://127.0.0.1:2379"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2020-10-26T21:49:58.889Z","caller":"clientv3/maintenance.go:208","msg":"completed snapshot read; closing"}
{"level":"info","ts":1603748998.9136698,"caller":"snapshot/v3_snapshot.go:142","msg":"fetched snapshot","endpoint":"https://127.0.0.1:2379","size":"5.9 MB","took":0.165411663}
{"level":"info","ts":1603748998.914325,"caller":"snapshot/v3_snapshot.go:152","msg":"saved","path":"/tmp/etcd-snapshot-2020-10-26_21:49:58_UTC.db"}
Snapshot saved at /tmp/etcd-snapshot-2020-10-26_21:49:58_UTC.db
```

Edit: A reproducible example using jobs, without passing any env vars:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: printf
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: printf
        image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.9-1
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
        - -c
        - echo `printf "%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z)T\n"`
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

```
# kubectl create -f job.yaml 
job.batch/printf created
# kubectl logs printf-lfcdh 
2020-10-27_10:03:59_UTC
```

Notice the use of backticks `` instead of $()

Comment: thanks! this worked, using it as one of the args in the backup script:    snapshot save /backup/etcd-snapshot-$(echo `printf "%(%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z)T\n"`).db